# Elastic Job sp_add_jobstep returns "Cannot reference the credential because it does not exist or you do not have permission"

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-database

I'm pretty new to Azure (and SQL for that matter). I've been trying to configure Elastic Jobs Agent with a few specific jobs that would run queries against some of my databases on the server.

For right now I am targeting a test database where I want to execute a simple select query. However, I can't create the job step because of the "can't reference the credential" error.

I'm not sure why the error is popping up. I have followed [Use T-SQL to create and manage Elastic Database Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-tsql-create-manage?view=azuresql) article and I created all of the credentials and logins as described there.

The one exception here is that the masterkey already exists so I didn't create that and I also did  not create a separate server for my agent host DB as suggested in some of the tutorials. My agent host DB sits on the same server where my target databases are but I would not think that would be an issue.

I have successfully created a target group and a target group member which is the specific database on this server that I want to query. I have also created the job I want to use.

The problem happens when I try to run this

```
DECLARE @step_id1 INT, @job_version1 INT;

EXEC jobs.sp_add_jobstep 
@job_name = N'Job1',                    
@step_id = @step_id1 OUTPUT,             
@step_name = N'Step1',                    
@command = N'select * from table',        
@credential_name = N'agentjobuser',       
@target_group_name = N'TestTarget'
```

I am at a loss here, I have no idea why it's saying that the credential doesn't exist. I am using the sql server admin login so I should definitely have the permissions for it.

Comment: Try this command `GRANT REFERENCES ON DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL::[{credential_name}] TO [{user}];`

Comment: credential name parameter should be the **database scoped credential** name. It is **not** SQL server admin user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to repro this and got the same error.

- When SQL server username is given as credential name parameter in the sp_add_jobstep, the same error is reproduced.

> Cannot reference the credential 'user', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

[image]

- Database scoped credential name which is created for SQL server user is given as value for the parameter `@credential_name`.  It is executed successfully without error.

[image]

Comment: thanks Aswin! I thought I created these as credentials but I just re-ran the CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL and I managed to create the job step. I will add that this time around I recreated everything through PowerShell.